# Selecting data from specific cells using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript with jQuery. I have script as;

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.ccc').click(function(index) {
  var $title = $(this);
  var $flag =  $title.parent().prev().children('.aaa').children('.bbb');
  var flag = $flag.text();
  alert(flag);
});
});
```

used with my table;

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">x</td>
    <td class="aaa">1<span class="bbb">q</span></td>
    <td class="aaa">2<span class="bbb">w</span></td>
    <td class="aaa">3<span class="bbb">e</span></td>
    <td class="aaa">4<span class="bbb">r</span></td>
    <td class="aaa">5<span class="bbb">t</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2">x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ccc">6</td>
    <td class="ccc">7</td>
    <td class="ccc">8</td>
    <td class="ccc">9</td>
    <td class="ccc">10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table has two rows (may contain more rows with same repeated pattern). The script is suppose to alert value on the cell just above the cell, `class="bbb"` I click `class="ccc"`. But instead, it displays data in all cells above that having `class="bbb"`. How can I solve this?

You can see my [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/hskVW/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you can do it as follows:

Get the index of the currently clicked cell:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

Then select the cell with this index *+ 1* from the previous row:

```
$('.ccc').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  var $flag =  $(this).parent().prev().children().eq(index + 1).children('.bbb');
  alert($flag.text());
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/hskVW/3/)

**Reference**: [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

**Update:** In fact, if every table cell only contains one `.bbb` element, you can also do:

```
var $flag =  $(this).parent().prev().find(`.bbb`).eq(index + 1);
```

Comment: this is useful, but i want to alert whats inside span.. Updated question

Comment: @blasteralfred: Ops, missed that. Just add `.children('.bbb')`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want.

```
$('.ccc').click(function(index) {
  var $t= $(this);
  var idx = $t.prevAll('.ccc').size();
  var $flag =  $t.parent().prev().children('.aaa').eq(idx).children('.bbb');
  var flag = $flag.text();
  alert(flag);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hskVW/1/

My second suggestion is ... well similar to abdullah.abcoder (the only difference is I think the result can be cache for event binding), please see :

```
var $c = $('.ccc');
$('.aaa').each(function(i){
    var $t = $(this);
    $c.eq(i).click(function(){
        alert($t.children('.bbb').text());
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hskVW/8/

My reason is, if your layout is not dynamic, you can retrieve the '.ccc' elements and bind the specific event only once, instead of traversing a lot in each click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.ccc').click(function(index) {
  var $title = $(this);
    var $flag =  $title.parent().prev().children('.aaa:first').prev();
  var flag = $flag.text();
  alert(flag);
});
});
```

Use the :first selector to get the first instance the class is used.

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrXQ/1

Comment: Any click will show you 'q'. Apparently this is not what blasteralfred wants

Comment: ???? I think your code will always bring up 'x', not the content of the cell above the cell clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try this: //output like: 1q/2w etc

```
$('.ccc').each(function(index, val) { (function() {
        $('.ccc:eq(' + index + ')').bind('click',
        function() {
            var $title = $(this);
            var $flag = $title.parent().prev().children('.aaa:eq(' + index + ')');
            var flag = $flag.text();
            alert(flag);
        });
    })(index)
});
```

another: //output like: q/w etc

```
$('.ccc').each(function(index, val) { (function() {
        $('.ccc:eq(' + index + ')').bind('click',
        function() {
            var $title = $(this);
            var $flag = $title.parent().prev().children('.aaa:eq(' + index + ')').children('.bbb');
            var flag = $flag.text();
            alert(flag);
        });
    })(index)
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `$('.ccc:eq(' + index + ')')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the eq to get only the desired item ;)

```
$('.ccc').click(function(index) {
  var index = $(this).index(); //here is the trick
  var $title = $(this);
  var $flag =  $title.parent().prev().children('.aaa:eq('+index+')').children('.bbb'); //and here our new selector
  var flag = $flag.text();
  alert(flag);
});
```